# Java - store current date WITHOUT TIME into a Text file

Tags: java, string, store, simpledateformat

I really need your help. I have searched and tried every example I could use, but none have worked.

I need to store current date in YYYY-MM-DD format in a text file..the `String date` has to be a string..

```
String dateF = "YYYY-MM-DD";
Date dateOnly = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateF);
String date = dateFormat.format(dateOnly);
```

when I tried that code above.. this the output I got

```
please|work|2016-04-110|11
```

please help me...this is my assignment due this Friday ): I just need this date and 2 other things to be done.. 
thanks :)

Comment: And where is the code you output the line? I guess the error is somewhere there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format being used is incorrect.

**YYYY-MM-*DD*** : Capital DD will return Day in the year. So, 11 April corresponds to 110th day in the year.

**yyyy-MM-*dd*** : Small dd will return the Day in the month.

Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: ohhhhh ok, I get it. i just tried it and it works. yay thanks :) :)

Answer (score 3):

your issue comes from the case you used for Y and D. according to the API [SimpleDateFormat documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you should use `d` (day in month) instead of `D` (day in year), in your format definition.

```
    String dateF = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(c.getTime());
```

The `formattedDate`  contain `2016-04-19`

#### Edit :

In your code change the `YYYY` to `yyyy` and `DD` to `dd`.